# Connect to wifi and broadband

Tags: wireless, internet, network-manager

I have a Bsnl broadband connection. Using Windows OS we connect our broadband in a different method:

1. When I start my D-link modem, my Win 7 wireless shows a connection that doesn't need any password. I just click it, then I connect.
2. After that I go to the network sharing center and click ppope and type my ISP's username and password and click “connect”, then it connects.

For connecting I need wireless connection and after that ppope. So I need to know how to get connected in Ubuntu with that. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Click the Network icon in the upper-right corner. Click 'Edit connections'.
Now click add and chose a DSL connection. Provide your username and password and click save. You can also enable 'connect automatically' and 'available to all users'. Now click on the network icon again and you will see "DSL connection 1" listed. Click on it and your computer will be conected to internet.

Comment: thanks for your answer but as i told you i need both connection to use, i use wifi instead of lan cable and password and username for connect, first i need to click in wifi and connect anyway then dial my connection in win7 but how use this method in ubuntu

Comment: Er, I have never connected to a wifi, so I have no idea. Sorry. Try searching in Google.